# Increasing the Vertical Gap Between Certain Description Items

Tags: enumitem, description, vertical-spacing, add-vertical-space

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=.3in,paperwidth=4in,paperheight=6in]{geometry}
\textheight=5.25in
\usepackage[frame,noinfo,center]{crop}

\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}

\setlist[description,2]{
    topsep=4\itemsep,
    itemindent=-25pt,
    leftmargin=15pt,
    before={\setcounter{enumii}{\value{enumi}}},
    after={\setcounter{enumi}{\value{enumii}}\vspace*{-\topsep}}
}

\newcommand*{\itemb}[1]{%
  \begin{description}\item #1\end{description}
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\small
\bfseries

\begin{description}
\item Original item.
\item Original item.
\item Original item.
\itemb{New Item (itemb). \lipsum[13]}
\itemb{New Item (itemb). \lipsum[13]}
\item Original item.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: How may I increase the vertical space between the `\itemb` items (i.e., those here with Latin) without affecting the vertical space between the original `\item` items?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How may I increase the vertical space between the \itemb items?

By actually having more than one item per level-2 description environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=.3in,
            paperwidth=4in,paperheight=6in]%
           {geometry}
%\textheight=5.25in % why not 5.4in?

\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}

\setlist[description,2]{
    topsep = 1.0\baselineskip, % space above/below level-2 descr. env.
    itemsep= 0.5\baselineskip, % space between level-2 descr. items
    leftmargin=15pt,
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\small

\begin{description}
\item[Original item.] \dots
\item[Original item.] \dots
\item[Original item.] \dots
\begin{description}
\item[New Item (itemb).] \lipsum[13][1-6]
\item[New Item (itemb).] \lipsum[13][1-6]
\end{description}
\item[Original item.] \dots
\item[Original item.] \dots
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks Mico.